# How can I diagnose a consistent high pitch noise that matches my cadence?

Tags: noise

I've been cycling on my Trek Emonda S4 for about 530 km so far and I've noticed a high-pitched but quiet sound while I'm out. It increases in volume and pitch as I increase my cadence. I'm concerned I could be doing some damage to it. The crankset is my suspicion. Is it possible that I haven't lubricated it properly or often enough?

Comment: Have you tried turning the pedals whilst standing next to the bike and lifting the rear wheel? This might give you a better idea where the sound is coming from and what the cause might be.

Comment: Try to move various things independently. While standing lift the rear wheel and turn the cranks. Is the noise still there? Is it also there when backpedalling? The first thing to try is to lube the chain. What if you turn the rear wheel alone? You can also try turning the cranks without chain.

Comment: When I get that it's my joints squeaking!

Comment: When you say the crankset is your suspicion, do you actually mean the chain?

Comment: @DanielRHicks [A squirt of oil should fix that...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=louBM-Mix7s)  :-D

Comment: That sounds like something rubbing - maybe in a bearing.  What kind of pedals?  Is the sound steady or does it rise and fall in sync with your pedaling?

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I prefer a shot of something!

Comment: @AndrewHenle Hips, knees & ankles rarely have grease nipples.

Comment: 540km, what age is the Trek? The warranty could still cover that (?) Take it to the seller. Could be a misaligned BB.

Comment: For years, I would hear a similar sound from time to time.  I finally figured out it was slight shoe rub onto a crank arm.  Not enough to cause paint wear, but just enough to make a high pitched sound.  Similar to a small bird chirp.

If you have this problem, see if slightly rotating your feet change the sound.

Comment: Did you ever find a cause?  Feel free to post your own answer if so.